# how to copy default constraints of columns in temp table?

Tags: sql-server, database

I tried to create a temp table with the following script

```
select *
into #Product
from (select * from SalesLT.Product) as data
```

Temp table got created and all the values inserted in new table. Now i am trying to insert a row in new temp table(#product) but i am getting error regarding some fields.

```
Insert into SalesLT.Product(Name, ProductNumber, StandardCost, ListPrice, ProductCategoryID, SellStartDate)
    values('LED Lights', 'LT-L123', 2.56, 12.99, 37, GETDATE()​)
```

Actually i have a default date constraint on one of the fields Modified Date in Product table but this constraint did not get copy into new temp table so it is throwing exception
**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ModifiedDate', table 'tempdb.dbo.#Product**

Is there any way to copy all the constraints in temp table?

Answer (score 0):

`Select into` won't copy any constraints like Primarykeys,foreign Keys..The only way to get them in destination table is to script them out manually..

The only thing copied by `select into` is Identity

```
select * into dbo.test/#test  from test1--only copies identity
```

Comment: @theGameiswar Is there any other way to get everything in temp table at once without creating constraints manually?

Comment: @RajaYuvi:no it won't

Comment: @ManishKumawat:There is no way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implicitly 'copy' or create constraints onto a temp table. You might consider looking at recreating the temp table as a mirror of the original by simply using the original tables' schema. In the same manner you can then recreate the indexes and constraints.

I would point you to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS,  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as a base for the coding.